# Comparing function results in python

Tags: python, loops, teamspeak

I am pretty new to python and I was wondering if anyone could help me out...
I am trying to write a script that checks if I have admin on my TS3 server. However I just can't figure it out after a whole day.

The api I use is linked here:
http://py-ts3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
    import time
    import ts3


    def admincheck(nickname, id):
        while True:
            client = ts3conn.clientdbfind(pattern=nickname)
            group = ts3conn.servergroupclientlist(sgid=id)
            for client in client:
                print("client db id:\n" + (client["cldbid"]))
            for group in group:
                print("client db ids with admin:\n" + (group["cldbid"]))
                time.sleep(1.5)
            if int(client["cldbid"]) in range(int(group["cldbid"])):
                print("client has admin")
            else:
                print("client does not admin")



    with ts3.query.TS3Connection("localhost") as ts3conn:
            ts3conn.login(
                    client_login_name="serveradmin",
                    client_login_password="<ommited>"
            )
            ts3conn.use(sid=1)
            admincheck("test", "6")
```

I think my problem is in this part:

```
    if int(client["cldbid"]) in range(int(group["cldbid"])):
            print("client has admin")
        else:
            print("client does not admin")
```

It would be great if someone could help :)
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Since I didn't state the question at hand (noob here), this is a sample output:

```
    client db id:
    2
    client db ids with admin:
    2
    client db ids with admin:
    3
    client db ids with admin:
    4
    client does not admin
```

As you can see, the output says that the client does not have admin, eventhough the client db id corresponds with an entry in the list with ids that have admin.

Comment: Fix your indentation and describe what happens. Do you get an error? Incorrect results?

Comment: *I think my problem is in this part* What problem? You haven't described a problem or asked a question.

Comment: Sorry guys, The problem is the output. It is supposed to check if a user is admin based on the database ID, what happens however is that it says not admin no matter what.

Comment: this is an output example:
client db id:
2
client db ids with admin:
2
client db ids with admin:
3
client db ids with admin:
4
client does not admin

Comment: Please edit your question when answering things from comments and place the answers as edit into the question itself. Comments are ill fitted for code.

Answer (score 0):

Great read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Problems:

```
def admincheck(nickname, id):
    while True:
        client = ts3conn.clientdbfind(pattern=nickname)
        group = ts3conn.servergroupclientlist(sgid=id)

        # you are overwriting your client-list with its first element
        # both have the same name
        for client in client:
            print("client db id:\n" + (client["cldbid"]))

        # you are overwriting your group-list with its first element
        # both have the same name
        for group in group:
            print("client db ids with admin:\n" + (group["cldbid"]))
            time.sleep(1.5)

        # you should check if any client-id is equal to any inside group-ids
        # instead you do something with range - wich does not make much sense?
        if int(client["cldbid"]) in range(int(group["cldbid"])):
            print("client has admin")
        else:
            print("client does not admin")
```

If you need to convert multiple numbers, use map:

```
text = [ "1","12","123","1234","12345"]
asInt = list( map(int,text))  # apply int() to each part of text, returns iterable 

print(asInt)  #   [1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345]

ids = ["5","7","1"] 
idNums = list(map(int,text))  # same 

print(any(x in asInt for x in idNums))   # checks if any x from idNums is 
                                         # inside asInt (your groupIds)
```

Output:

```
[1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345]
True
```

Doku: [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)